# Flutter_how i can solve the test problem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am facing one error when i try to test my codes like in the picture in bellow.
  [image]

Comment: Seems that flutter cannot find the correct dart cache, try `flutter clean`, or follow the installation guide again.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you have a wrong import statment.
Go to the top of your code and remove the line that has `import dart:ui`.

That would solve the problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: I didnot use the import you wrote  "impot dart:ui"